# How does this click handler get assigned to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Now that I understand Backbone a little better (I Hope) I've been going through this App with a fine tooth comb to understand how it works:

https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/tree/master/public

The latest thing that's stumped me is the EL tag in windetails.js (here: https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/public/js/views/winedetails.js)

I'll paste the relevant code below, but my question is how does this view's EL property get assigned? As you'll notice in the view definition no EL tag is defined, nor is there an idTag or className property assigned. However I verified in firebug that this view is indeed listening on a DIV tag in the middle of the DOM (just underneath the content DIV actually). So how did it get attached there? If not for that the Click handler would not work properly but it does. All of the previous views which look like there were created in the same way have unattached EL properties.

```
window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "change" : "change",
        "click .save" : "beforeSave",
        "click .delete" : "deleteWine",
        "drop #picture" : "dropHandler"
    },

    change: function (event) {
        // Remove any existing alert message
        utils.hideAlert();

        // Apply the change to the model
        var target = event.target;
        var change = {};
        change[target.name] = target.value;
        this.model.set(change);

        // Run validation rule (if any) on changed item
        var check = this.model.validateItem(target.id);
        if (check.isValid === false) {
            utils.addValidationError(target.id, check.message);
        } else {
            utils.removeValidationError(target.id);
        }
    },

    beforeSave: function () {
        var self = this;
        var check = this.model.validateAll();
        if (check.isValid === false) {
            utils.displayValidationErrors(check.messages);
            return false;
        }
        this.saveWine();
        return false;
    },

    saveWine: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log('before save');
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function (model) {
                self.render();
                app.navigate('wines/' + model.id, false);
                utils.showAlert('Success!', 'Wine saved successfully', 'alert-success');
            },
            error: function () {
                utils.showAlert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying to delete this item', 'alert-error');
            }
        });
    },

    deleteWine: function () {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function () {
                alert('Wine deleted successfully');
                window.history.back();
            }
        });
        return false;
    },

    dropHandler: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var e = event.originalEvent;
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        this.pictureFile = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

        // Read the image file from the local file system and display it in the img tag
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            $('#picture').attr('src', reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.pictureFile);
    }

});
```

**EDIT**
There's been a lot of talk about this pattern:
$(x).append(v.render().el)

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand it this is a Jquery call to update the DOM at the "x" tag with the contents of the "el" property from the v object (after render is called). This technique should render content into the DOM EVEN IF the "el" property has not previously been set and is an "unattached div" provided it has had valid content previously written to it from the render method.

However after the content has been written to the DOM the "el" property still remains an unattached div until it is directly assigned to the DOM.

I verified through Firebug that this Backbone app has two views which are rendered this exact way and both have unattached div el properties. Those are the wineList view and the homeView. However, the 3rd view is the WineDetail view and it does not seem to have an unattached EL property. It's EL property seems to be attached and furthermore is facilitating a click event. My question is how did this EL property get attached and assigned to the DOM?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The [`View#el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) and [`View#delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) parts might be helpful. You could always study the Backbone source too, it is fairly small, simple, and easy to understand.

Comment: I read it yeah. I understand that the view.delegateEvents is listening for a click action on buttons with certain classes. But I also tested and verified two scenarios. 1) Without an EL property that's attached to the DOM events will NOT trigger 2) In firebug I verified this particular view IS somehow attached to a DIV in the middle of the DOM. My question, again, is how did this EL tag get assigned?

Comment: ["`this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties, if specified. If not, `el` is an empty `div`."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) As to how it gets in the DOM, have a look at who instantiates it, the usual pattern is `v = new View; $(x).append(v.render().el)`.

Comment: I'm glad we agree that the el property should be an empty div in this case. But I'm sorry I don't see how the details of the instantiation are relevant. As you said yourself the 4 factors are tagname, classname, id, and attributes. None of which are set correct? In fact the previous view before this one (called WineListView) was instantiated in the same way and it *does* have an empty div as an EL property. So why not this one?

Comment: I hope you don't think I am just nitpicking. This is all very relevant to me at the moment because I'm trying to track down a bug in my OWN Backbone app right now that's causing clicks to get triggered twice. In order to troubleshoot that I feel like I need to better understand how event binding and EL assignments work.

Comment: Yes, `el` starts off as an empty `<div>` and then `render` puts stuff in it, the events are attached by `delegateEvents` which is called by the view constructor. Then someone (probably whoever instantiated the view) puts that `el` on the page. Maybe I just don't see what the question is.

Comment: If you're getting doubled events then you probably have a zombie view and that tends to happen when you pass an `el` to a view when instantiating it but you don't properly clean things up before handing the same `el` to another view.

Comment: Ok, I made an edit in my post to help clarify my question. Maybe that will help. Maybe I've just been at this too long....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found by looking at the internals of `Backbone.View`.

Looking at the constructor:

```
  var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    this._configure(options || {});
    //this function is responsible for the creation of the `this.el` property.
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.delegateEvents();
  };
```

> Ensure that the View has a DOM element to render into. If this.el is a
>   string, pass it through $(), take the first matching element, and
>   re-assign it to el. Otherwise, create an element from the id,
>   className and tagName properties. *http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-133*

Now that we know where `this.el` comes from, have a look at the [events docs](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-130) to see how it's handled.

The view is instantiated in [main.js](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/public/js/main.js)

```
$('#content').html(new WineView({model: wine}).el);
```

**EDIT:**

> None of which explains how the View Object's EL property is set and
>   and how the click trigger works.

I will try to explain it better:

`this.el` is created by a call to `this._ensureElement` in the `Backbone.View` constructor. We can also see that `this.render` is called from the `initialize` function which runs at instanciation time. We can see that in `this.render`, we set the content of `this.el` to the result of applying `this.template` to the model.

Now, during the initialization process of a `Backbone.View`, right after `this.initialize` is called, the `events` config is processed by making a call to `this.delegateEvents`. This is where event listeners will get attached using the given selectors. *Note that most events will get attached directly to `this.el` and make use of event delegation, instead of attaching the events directly on the children elements.*

At this point, we are left with a `this.el` that contains all the necessary markup and has all the event listeners setup. However, `this.el` is still not part of the DOM yet.

But from the code, we can see that `this.el` will be attached to the DOM as a children of the `#content` element after the instanciation of the view:

```
$('#content').html(new WineView({model: wine}).el);
```

Comment: Ok, but the code I referenced has no id, className, tagName, NOR does it have a this.el string. So therefore it should be assigned an unattached Div tag correct? And if this.el is an unattached div tag then will the event handler still catch click events properly from the DOM?

Comment: @user1813867 You need to look at the code that instanciate the view. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I don't feel that adequately answers my question. The code you added can be explained like this: We are constructing a new WineView object and passing it the wine model. If you look at the WineView constructor code you'll see this causes a call to the render method which in turn renders a model and a template to the View instance's this.el property. Then, finally, the this.el propery is used in that jquery call you just pasted to update the DOM directly to the '#content' element. None of which explains how the View Object's EL property is set and and how the click trigger works.

Comment: @user1813867, Everything is there. It's juste perhaps, not explained well enough. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you it was your last post that cleared it up for me. I didn't realize that Jquery call also attached the EL's property into the DOM. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The last three lines in this piece of code:

```
events: {
    "change" : "change",
    "click .save" : "beforeSave",
    "click .delete" : "deleteWine",
    "drop #picture" : "dropHandler"
},
```

look like this pattern (looking at the 2nd line in the events structure):

```
"click" = event to register a handler for
".save" = selector to use for selecting objects for the event handler
beforeSave = method to call when the event fires
```